# Tomcat tcnative build on solaris

Tags: tomcat, openssl, tomcat7, solaris, fips

**I'm trying to install tomcat tc-native on my solaris machine**

```
uname -a
SunOS ovtasun4 5.10 Generic_147440-01 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-V240
# which cc
/opt/solarisstudio12.4/bin/cc
```

**And i configure it like this,**

```
./configure --with-apr=/usr/local/apr/bin/apr-1-config --with-java-home=$JAVA_HOME --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl --prefix=$CATALINA_HOME
```

**But make command is giving this error while building**

```
dladdr                              0x85c       /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o)
ld: fatal: relocations remain against allocatable but non-writable sections
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
*** Error code 1
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `libtcnative-1.la'
Current working directory /tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.29/bin/tomcat-native-1.1.33-src/jni/native
*** Error code 1
The following command caused the error:
otarget=`echo all-recursive | sed s/-recursive//`; \
list='src os/unix os/win32 '; \
for i in $list; do \
    if test -f "$i/Makefile"; then \
        target="$otarget"; \
        echo "Making $target in $i"; \
        if test "$i" = "."; then \
            made_local=yes; \
            target="local-$target"; \
        fi; \
        (cd $i && make $target) || exit 1; \
    fi; \
done; \
        if test "$otarget" = "all" && test -z "libtcnative-1.la"; then \
    made_local=yes; \
fi; \
if test "$made_local" != "yes"; then \
    make "local-$otarget" || exit 1; \
fi
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `all-recursive'
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you building 64-bit?  If so, you must compile with the [`-kPIC/-kpic`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37069_01/html/E37074/bjapp.html#OSSCGbjarj) or the proper [`-xcode=picX`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37069_01/html/E37074/bjapp.html#OSSCGbjatt) option, as Solaris shared objects [pretty much require position-independent code](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E26507/glmqp.html), and there are also 32-bit cases where you must do the same:

> The code within a dynamic executable is typically position-dependent,
>   and is tied to a fixed address in memory. Shared objects, on the other
>   hand, can be loaded at different addresses in different processes.
>   Position-independent code is not tied to a specific address. This
>   independence allows the code to execute efficiently at a different
>   address in each process that uses the code. Position-independent code
>   is recommended for the creation of shared objects.
>
> The compiler can generate position-independent code under the -K pic
>   option.
>
> If a shared object is built from position-dependent code, the text
>   segment can require modification at runtime. This modification allows
>   relocatable references to be assigned to the location that the object
>   has been loaded. The relocation of the text segment requires the
>   segment to be remapped as writable. This modification requires a swap
>   space reservation, and results in a private copy of the text segment
>   for the process. The text segment is no longer sharable between
>   multiple processes. Position-dependent code typically requires more
>   runtime relocations than the corresponding position-independent code.
>   Overall, the overhead of processing text relocations can cause serious
>   performance degradation.